# JOINING two tables to get data

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I want to get my location `city` and `country` data from my database `location`.

This is my code:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("
SELECT 
u.`prename`,
u.`surname`,
DATE_FORMAT(u.`birthday`, '%d. %M') AS bday,
l.`city`,
l.`country`

FROM 
`users` AS u
LEFT JOIN `users_location` AS ul ON ul.`uid` = u.`id`
LEFT JOIN `locations` AS l ON l.`id` = ul.`location_id`

WHERE u.`id`='".(int) ($_GET['id'])."'"));
```

In `users_location` is assigned which user has which `location_id`.

(`users_location` structure: `id`, `uid`, `location_id`)

In `locations` are the `city` and `country` names.

However `city` and `country` is empty using my query. I guess because of my join statement?

Comment: The statement looks correct to me.

Comment: What's the question? Yes, that's what a "left join" is, but do you have a problem?

Comment: Please sanitize your GET Variable before using it :/

Comment: Kerrek SB: I don't receive any data using this query. @demonking: What do you mean by sanitize?

Comment: I mean that what Luke Marlow has wrote in his edit ;)
He has checked the $_GET before using it

Comment: What do you mean "not any data"? Surely you're receiving the user IDs?

Comment: (Maybe you meant an ordinary *inner* join? That's just spelt `JOIN`.)

Comment: So the casting the $_GET-Var with `(int)` isn't enough?

Comment: Vay, that would depend on how you wish to write code. Type-casting in-line is quite sloppy, in my opinion, and should your numbers ever exceed the INT max (Code: 2.147B -=- DB: signed: 2.147B, unsigned: 4.294B unsigned) you will have to edit every file in your system.

That said, if you exceed the limit of INT, while unsigned, I would say you were possibly doing something wrong.

Comment: I see. So, do you think it would be recommended to write a function that checks a specific id-value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used "LEFT JOIN `table` AS t.

Simply "LEFT JOIN `table` t", like so;

```
SELECT 
    u.`prename`, u.`surname`, DATE_FORMAT(u.`birthday`, '%d. %M') AS bday, 
    l.`city`, l.`country`
FROM  `users` u
LEFT JOIN  `users_location` ul ON  ul.`uid` = u.`id`
LEFT JOIN  `locations` l  ON  l.`id` = ul.`location_id`
WHERE u.`id` = {$id};
```

EDIT:
And please consider checking data and not just doing what you have done.

Something to the effect of;

```
$id = (array_key_exists('id', $_GET) && is_string($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']))
    ? $_GET['id'] : FALSE :
if ($id)
{
    SELECT 
        u.`prename`, u.`surname`, DATE_FORMAT(u.`birthday`, '%d. %M') AS bday, 
        l.`city`, l.`country`
    FROM  `users` u
    LEFT JOIN  `users_location` ul ON  ul.`uid` = u.`id`
    LEFT JOIN  `locations` l  ON  l.`id` = ul.`location_id`
    WHERE u.`id` = {$id};
}
else
{
    echo 'No valid ID was provided.';
}
```